# How to reduce cognitive complexity in java code

Tags: java, sonarqube

Please advise how to reduce cognitive complexity on the below code

```
ids.add((row.getCell(11) != null) ? row.getCell(11).getStringCellValue() : "");
```

Comment: The first thing I would try is calling `row.getCell(11)` only once, instead of twice:   `Cell cell = row.getcell(11); ids.add(cell != null ? cell.getStringValue() : "");`

Comment: @Sony Why did you edit an answer to the question?

Answer (score 5):

Add a method to hide the details, for example:

```
private String getCellValueOrDefault(Cell cell) {
    if (cell == null) {
       return "";
    }
    return cell.getStringValue();
}
```

Then use the method:

```
ids.add(getCellValueOrDefault(row.getCell(11));
```

Comment: Isn't this a very problematic solution at scale? @Andrew-S

Comment: @Robert - not sure what you mean - can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Optional:

```
ids.add(Optional
  .ofNullable(row.getCell(11))
  .map(cell -> cell.getStringCellValue())
  .orElse("")
)
```

That way you don't need an extra method. If this is something that is needed at many places it is better to create a specific method for at as Andrew S remarked.