# What's the best way to perform a 1 line functionality in java 8 based on a boolean flag?

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have a boolean flag based on which I want to perform a 1 line functionality say increment a variable or call an object's method etc. What's the best way to do this with min **cognitive complexity** in java 8?

```
// Objects a is initialized;
// int x, y;
// boolean flag;
if (flag) {
    a.doSomething1();
} else {
    a.doSomethingElse1();
}

// want to check multiple times like this
if (flag) {
    a.doSomething2();
} else {
    a.doSomethingElse2();
}

if (flag) {
    x++;
} else {
    y++;
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do these in java 8 by reducing cognitive complexity? as I'm facing a problem with this sonarlint rule : **Cognitive Complexity of methods should not be too high** with too many if else statements

---------- EDIT -----------------

my code looks something like this :

```
void myMethod(List<SomeClass> list) {
    for (SomeClass a : list) {
        SomeClass a;
        String name = a.getName();
        boolean flag = a.getFlag();
        switch(name) {
            case "name1":
                if (flag) a.doSomething1() else a.doSomethingElse1();
                break;
            case "name2":
                if (flag) a.doSomething2() else a.doSomethingElse2();
                break;
            //.... similar otherCases
        }
    }
}
```

All these are increasing cognitive complexity

Comment: Just put everything inside the same `if` or `else`. Or are you asking something else?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to simplify here. `if(a) b else c` is already pretty short.

Comment: if you meant doing this if (flag) x++ else y++ that wouldn't solve my problem, as it would still increment sonar lint cognitive complexity by whatever nesting factor - https://rules.sonarsource.com/java?search=cognitive%20complexity

Comment: @user97 what I'm saying is that there's no reason you can't do `if (flag) { a.doSomething1(); a.doSomething2(); x++; } else { a.doSomethingElse1(); a.doSomethingElse2(); y++ }` (unless, that is, any of those methods modifies `flag`)

Comment: The solution for cogntive complexity of a function being too high is to refactor the large function into multiple smaller functions, not to use a different construct that is not discovered/counted by the static analyzer.

Comment: there'll be different objects being incremented inside switch case inside for loops, which's increasing cognitive complexity

Comment: I am not familiar with the way how "cognitive complexity" is measured, but when it is about the difficulty of understanding the code then there are a few "standards" you could apply: avoid negative ifs `if(isEmpty)` instead of `if(!isEmpty)`, apply a fail first at the beginning of the method when your if would become to large `if(x==null) return` and minimise complex conditions.

Comment: See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994987/how-to-reduce-cognitive-complexity-in-java-code

Comment: In general, if there is a loop containing non-trivial logic, extract the body to a different function. This also helps with compliance to other rules, such as limited levels of nesting. If you have multiple boolean flags, you might be able to extract the parts that are equal and the parts that are distinct, and use patterns like Template Method or Strategy Pattern. But which one to choose depends on multiple factors, and cannot be answered in general.

Comment: Following up on @Hulk's comment - notice how your edited example extracts data from `a`, then uses the data to make a decision on what to do.  This behavior should be within `SomeClass` itself.  See also: Tell, Don't Ask

Answer (score 1):

To answer your concrete example:

As everything only depends on members of `SomeClass`, the logic should arguably be part of this class as well. One way would be:

```
abstract class SomeClass {               

    public void doIt() {
        String name = this.getName();
        switch (name) {
        case "name1":
            this.doName1();
            break;
        case "name2":
            this.doName2();
            break;
        }
    }
    
    private void doName1() {
        if (this.getFlag())
            this.doSomething1();
        else
            this.doSomethingElse1();
    }

    private void doName2() {
        if (this.getFlag())
            this.doSomething2();
        else
            this.doSomethingElse2();
    }
    
    abstract protected String getName();

    abstract protected boolean getFlag();

    abstract protected void doSomething1();

    abstract protected void doSomething2();

    abstract protected void doSomethingElse1();

    abstract protected void doSomethingElse2();
}
```

`myMethod` can then be either

```
void myMethod(List<SomeClass> list) {
    for (SomeClass a : list) {
        a.doIt();
    }
}
```

or be rewritten as

```
void myMethod(List<SomeClass> list) {
    list.forEach(SomeClass::doIt);
}
```

if you prefer, but that is mostly a matter of style/personal preference.

---

From that point, you can then start to consider splitting the methods ending with `1` and `2` to separate strategy Objects.

Also note how we are suddenly only using one single method from the outside anymore - this can be used to reduce the public interface of `SomeClass`, for the concrete example we only need `doIt()` to be public. This is an application of a principle often referred to as "Tell, don't Ask". Avoid asking Objects about the contents of their fields, to make decisions based on these values. Instead, tell them what you want to happen, and leave the details to them.